# Should it be clearer that auto-generated comments are auto-generated?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, comments, automatic-comments

I've started reviewing low quality posts recently, and hence some autogenerated comments have been added, e.g.:

> This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or
>   request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post
>   - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient reputation you will be able to comment on any post.

These sorts of auto generated comments *tend* to be on posts by newer users (especially the above one because of commenting privileges), who don't understand and often try to engage in return, e.g.:

> And what I just did wrong ? Just answer my post question and stop
>   criticizing the way I make comment

This is a particularly unhelpful one, but I've had a few others. Is there a way of making it clearer that the comment isn't specifically from me, or that it's auto-generated. I don't mind people engaging - as asking why I marked a post as low quality is potentially valid - but I think perhaps the tone of the auto-comments sets people on edge.

Comment: In a sense the comment _is_ from you. That was your decision on that question/answer. I like those since that means I don't have to type it out. Having an auto generated text would make it feel _more_ robotic I think. If the message was more human I don't think the OP would be less dejected.

Comment: Doesn't matter whether it's marked auto-comment or not. If you take a closer look, the OP is violently disinterested in anything but an answer, which is the real problem.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Yes, this is a bad example, it was just the one that occurred today.

Answer (score 7):

The problem isn't that auto-comments aren't prominently marked as such.
It isn't even that your comment was in any way questionable.

The problem is that the OP isn't in any way receptive to criticism, **he just wants his answer, now**, and GTFO instead of irritating him with anything else.

Don't engage, just downvote and move on.
Though if he gets too irritating, you could flag for moderator-intervention.

Answer (score 0):

> perhaps the tone of the auto-comments sets people on edge.

Well isn't that *absolutely terrible*. I can't even begin to imagine the long-term emotional trauma of being told to abide by the site's rules. Maybe these poor people should harden the f**k up. Even better, maybe they should actually read the rules before they come and break them.

The current auto-comments are already wish-washy enough ("this does not really answer the question"... no, it doesn't answer the question **at all**!). SO does not exist to cater to the lowest common denominator and vampires. There is a quality bar, and if people aren't willing to meet it they must GTFO.

Comment: Talking about the site's rule and abiding by them.... "BE NICE"

Comment: @Patrice: This might be a bit more spicy than strictly neccessary, probably due to exasperation. But, especially considering it's on meta, I don't think it's even close to breaching that rule.

Comment: @deduplicator I'm sorry, what? condescension, straight up insults... no I'm sorry, it is not being nice at all. I understand the sentiment and definitely agree with the premise here. But if I post an answer saying "maybe they should actually read the rules before they come and break them." When I'm not even able to follow the simple "be nice" policy, maybe I shouldn't post? Exasperation is no more an excuse for breaching this than urgency is an excuse for breaking the quality guidelines

Comment: @Patrice You seem to forget that "be nice" works both ways. If a new user joins and posts garbage because they don't know the rules because they didn't bother to read them, then is aggressive towards other users who are following said rules - are they being nice? If you have infinite time and patience, by all means, be nice to everybody. I choose to be nice to people who show they deserve niceness.

Comment: @IanKemp again, I'm ok with your premise, and the OP who comes in stomping his feet asking for his answer NOW isn't being nice or respectful to any of us. I just don't feel that "they did it first" is okay for us to retaliate in kinfd

Comment: @Patrice I agree with that, and I always do my best to be nice to everyone, regardless of how they respond to me... it's just that sometimes, seeing people being so ungrateful makes me... UGH.

Comment: @IanKemp yeah I know that feeling to be fair. I know I've left my fair share of that type of "UGH" comments as well. Sorry if I seemed a little bit aggravated at that :P. I was in need of a coffee :P. It's hard to always stay calm on Meta with the amount of nonsense we see sometimes